# Proving associativity of Matrices

Tags: matrices

If A,B,C are 3 matrices then (AB)C = A(BC)
Some people prove this (computationally) by saying "matrix multiplication start from left to right so it's trivial because in LHS we multiply C TO B THEN TO A and in RHS we multiply C TO B THEN TO A which is the same thing" but i think brackets are present, 
so in LHS we first multiply B TO A (not A to B)then C TO BA. In RHS we multiply C TO B THEN CB TO A. 
Who is right?

Comment: This is associativity, not commutativity.

Comment: never in the history of math, ever, was the associativity of matrix multiplication was proved like that. You need to use the actual matrix multiplication rule to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the associativity of matrix product is not trivial. 
You can prove it by writing down the three matrices and direct computation.

Or, in (again in my opinion) a more elegant way, by considering the linear operators represented by the matrices in some basis, and use the link between composition of operators (and associativity of this composition) and matrix product.

These sentences like  "we multiply C TO B THEN TO A and in RHS we multiply C TO B THEN TO A" do not mean much to me.